# F-test variance using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

My goal is to evaluate the null model that the variation in rainfall is the same for seeded clouds as it is for unseeded clouds.

```
cloudS_data <- read.csv('http://faculty.cord.edu/reber/data/205/CR1/CloudSeeding.csv')
cloudS_data

grpCloudsData <- cloudS_data %>% group_by(treatment)
grpCloudsData %>% summarise(rainfall = var(rainfall))
```

Thanks,

Comment: Can't you use the [var.test](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/var.test.html) function ?

Comment: Dividing one variance by the other gives you the F statistic, which you then compare with an F distribution with the right number of degrees of freedom. If you are interested in computing this as an exercise in understanding the theory, carry on, but if all you care about really is testing the hypothesis then I guess @StéphaneLaurent has the answer.

Answer (score 1):

[F-test of equality of variances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-test_of_equality_of_variances)  is so sensitive to the assumption of normality

[Bartlett's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bartlett%27s_test) is also sensitive to the assumption of normality.

I Social science the most prevailing Homogeneity of Variance test is [Levene's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levene%27s_test) which is an alternative to the Bartlett test. The Levene test is less sensitive than the Bartlett test to departures from normality. If you have strong evidence that your data do come from a normal, or nearly normal, distribution, then Bartlett's test has better performance.[source](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda35a.htm)

[Brown–Forsythe test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown%E2%80%93Forsythe_test) provides good robustness against many types of non-normal data while retaining good statistical power.

so let use Brown–Forsythe test:

```
library(onewaytests)
bf.test(rainfall  ~ treatment, data = cloudS_data)
```

Result:

```
Brown-Forsythe Test (alpha = 0.05) 
------------------------------------------------------------- 
  data : rainfall and treatment 

  statistic  : 3.992982 
  num df     : 1 
  denom df   : 33.85525 
  p.value    : 0.05377346 

  Result     : Difference is not statistically significant. 
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

And F test:

```
var.test(rainfall  ~ treatment, data = cloudS_data)
```

Result:

```
    F test to compare two variances

data:  rainfall by treatment
F = 5.4633, num df = 25, denom df = 25, p-value = 6.695e-05
alternative hypothesis: true ratio of variances is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
  2.44959 12.18487
sample estimates:
ratio of variances 
          5.463326
```

Levene Test:

```
lawstat::levene.test(cloudS_data$rainfall , cloudS_data$treatment, location = "mean")
```

Result:

```
    Classical Levene's test based on the absolute deviations from the mean ( none not applied because
the location is not set to median )

data:  cloudS_data$rainfall
Test Statistic = 6.0876, p-value = 0.01708
```